# Xinetd obtain remote IP with PHP

Tags: php, tcp, xinetd

**Hello I have this service with xinetd:**

```
service MyService 
{
port = 8881
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = nobody
server = /usr/local/bin/php
server_args = /home/file/public_html/php/port/test1.php
log_on_success + = USERID
log_on_failure + = USERID
disable = no
}
```

**My File test1.php:**

```
<? php
$handle = fopen ('php :/ / stdin', 'r');
$input = fgets ($ handle);
fclose ($ handle);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
echo "Hello {$ input} your IP: $ip";
?>
```

**I can not get the remote ip:**

```
$ip = $ _SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

**As I can get the remote ip??**

Comment: check `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is modifying the PHP with :

**$IpX = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] : $_SERVER['HOST'];**

```
<? php
$IpX = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] : $_SERVER['HOST'];
$handle = fopen ('php :/ / stdin', 'r');
$input = fgets ($ handle);
fclose ($ handle);
echo "Hello {$ input} your IP: $IpX";
?>
```

Thanks to:  [Gonzalo Ayuzo](http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/building-network-services-with-php-and-xinetd/)

Answer (score 1):

`$REMOTE_ADDR` is an environment variable that is set by a web server as part of the CGI protocol. You're running straight on a socket. There is no web server here. It is not surprising that this variable (or indeed the ones suggested by [Laxus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711206/laxus) in a comment) aren't set.

If you want the remote address, you will have to get it yourself using [getpeername](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-getpeername.php).

Comment: Is the observation with respect to the solution of Laxus.

Seek information about your solution, because by the time getpeername do not know.

if I can lend a help regarding getpeername thank you

Comment: I have this:
`socket_getsockname ($socket, $IPX, $PORT);`
but $ IPX is Null, that I have wrong?

Comment: I correct is: `socket_getpeername ($socket, $IPX, $port); ` but do not get the remote ip.

Comment: When I run this command: `socket_getpeername ($socket, $IPX, $port);`

I get this error:

`Warning: socket_getpeername () Expects parameter 1 to be resource`

Comment: `socket_geetpeername` only works for actual sockets. xinetd binds the TCP socket to PHP's stdin/stdout, so `socket_getpeername` will simply error.

Answer (score 1):

I tested and found that:

Apache httpd passes "**REMOTE_ADDR**" and "**REMOTE_PORT**" and much more other environments to the CGI program.

But xinetd passes only "**REMOTE_HOST**" environment to my program defined by "server" in xinetd.d/xxxx 。and more， "REMOTE_HOST" looks like "::ffff:192.168.1.23" , not a pure IP address.(BTW: what does this mean ?)

So : xinetd + program can only acts a tiny httpd moudle